# Load data from txt file to comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, streamreader

Hi i have this structure of txt file:

```
Lukas 1
Zdenek 3
Martin 2
Kate 1
```

And i need load this data...the name i need load to comboBox...and when i choose from `ComboBox` for example Lukas, i need to save Name Lukas to variable Name and number 1 to variable Number...

It is possible?

I have this code now...

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Us...nka\example.txt"))
{
    string data = "";
    data = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

But i need read separately Name and separately Number...Have you any ideas? Thanks..

Comment: Break it down into manageable chunks: read the lines first, split them then create combobox items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines` and `String.Split`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Us...nka\example.txt");
var data = lines.Select(l => l.Split());
```

I would use a class to store both properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can load the persons in a loop or with LINQ:

```
List<Person> allPersons = data
   .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 2 && arr[1].Trim().All(Char.IsDigit))
   .Select(arr => new Person
   {
       PersonName = arr[0].Trim(),
       PersonID = int.Parse(arr[1].Trim())
   })
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

> Yes thanks...but i cant load PersonsName to combobox

You can use a `BindingSource` for the `ComboBox`. Then set the [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties accordingly:

```
var bindingSourcePersons = new BindingSource();
bindingSourcePersons.DataSource = allPersons;
personComboBox.DataSource = bindingSourcePersons.DataSource;
personComboBox.ValueMember = "PersonID";
personComboBox.DisplayMember = "PersonName";
```

Comment: Thanks...i tried this...i havent any error, data is loaded in allPersons, but comcoBox is empty :// Any ideas?

Comment: @Kate: Try it with a `BindingSource`, edited again. Maybe the order was wrong, so you could also try to use the list as datasource directly but set the datasource first before you set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` (i don't use winforms often).

Comment: after this Still empty :/

Comment: @Kate: But yu're sure that the list contains persons? Instead of `personComboBox.DataSource = bindingSourcePersons.DataSource` try `personComboBox.DataSource = bindingSourcePersons`. Otherwise i have no idea what's going on. Maybe you need to ask another question that addresses exactly this issue. However, there are already questions on SO about how to bind a list of custom type to a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class like this:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

then you can use Linq to convert the string you read like this:

```
var people = data
            .Split(new {'\r','\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(d => new Person { Name = d.Split(' ')[0], Value = int.Parse(d.Split(' ')[1])})
            .ToList();
```

Or better you could read your data line by line, like this:

```
var people = from l in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Us...nka\example.txt")
             let parts = l.Split(' ')
             select new Person { 
                          Name = parts[0].Trim(), 
                          Value = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim())
                            };
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a pseudo:

while the reader is not EndOfStream
read current line
split the line that was just read into a string[] array, the separator being a space
first item in the array would be the name and the second item in the array would be the number.
then you add the item in the combo box. The combobox has an Items collection and an add method, which just takes a System.Object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551(v=vs.71).aspx